# HTTPS redirect when URL not prefaced with HTTP://

Tags: url, redirect, https, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have found numerous answers to redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS but can't figure out how to redirect when the user only types the domain name without the protocol prefix.

Specifically....

The site is hosted on a Win2008r2 server with IIS7. One site in question is using .NET 2.0 and the other on the same server is 4.5. I'm successfully using the rewrite module so that HTTP ://www.Example.com redirects to HTTPS ://www.Example.com. However www.Example.com and Example.com both change to HTTP:// in the address bar but doesn't redirect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, which works when entering `http://www.example.com`, but it doesn’t work when entering `www.example.com` (which the browser changes to `http://www.example.com`)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Typing www.example.com or www.example.com just goes to the http site and does not redirect to https